# jQuery-Validation-Engine - Validation File MIME Type

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I would like to use the jQuery-Validation-Engine to validate the MIME Type of a file input. How could I do this?

My approach would be something like this:

```
function checkMIME(field, rules, i, options){
    var file = $("#userfile")[0].files[0];
    var MimeFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;
    if (! MimeFilter.test(file.type)) {
     return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
  }
}
```

Thanx
Kashuda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, found a solution by adding these lines to the `query.validationEngine-LANG.js`:

```
"validateMIME":  {
    "func": function(field, rules, i, options){
   //add to input tag: data-validation-engine="validate[required, custom[validateMIME[image/jpeg|image/png]]]"

    var fileInput = field[0].files[0];
    var MimeFilter = new RegExp(rules[3],'i');

    if (fileInput) {
        return MimeFilter.test(fileInput.type);
    } else { return true;}
  },
"alertText": "* Wrong Mime Type."

},
```

Comment: @Kashuda - this code is work for wrong mime type...but this validation is also fired for right mimetype..

Answer (score 4):

By modifying your code, I have implemented another way to validate File MIME type:

First append the following code into the '_validateField' method of jquery.validationEngine.js file

```
case "checkFileType":
errorMsg = methods._checkFileType(field, rules, i, options);
break;
```

Then append the following code into the same file

```
_checkFileType: function (field, rules, i, options) {
        var uploadedFile = $(field);
        if (uploadedFile) {
            var extensions = rules[i + 1];               
            var mimeFilter = new RegExp(extensions);
            if (!mimeFilter.test($(uploadedFile).val().split('.').reverse()[0])) {
                return options.allrules.checkFileType.alertText;
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }            
    },
```

Finally,
append the following line to jquery.validationEngine-en.js file

```
"checkFileType": {
                    "regex": "none",
                    "alertText": "* Wrong file Type."                    
                },
```

Usage:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="myfile" class="validate[checkFileType[jpg|jpeg|gif|JPG|png|PNG]]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to jquery.validationEngine.js if the image is not required option  add to input tag:

```
class="validate[optional, custom[validateMIME[image/jpeg|image/png]]]"
```

If it is a required field add

add to input tag:

```
class="validate[required, custom[validateMIME[image/jpeg|image/png]]]"



"validateMIME":  {
    "func": function(field, rules, i, options){
   //add to input tag: data-validation-engine="validate[required, custom[validateMIME[image/jpeg|image/png]]]"

    var fileInput = field[0].files[0];
    var MimeFilter = new RegExp(rules[3],'i');

    if (fileInput) {
        return MimeFilter.test(fileInput.type);
    } else { return true;}
    },
    "alertText": "* Wrong Mime Type."

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

In form field

```
class="validate[required], custom[validateMIME[pdf|doc|docx]"
```

In query.validationEngine-LANG.js

```
"validateMIME": {   

    "func": function(field, rules, i, options){
            var uploadedFile = $(field);  

            if (uploadedFile) {
            var extensions = rules[i+2];               
            var mimeFilter = new RegExp(extensions);                     

            return (mimeFilter.test($(uploadedFile).val().split('.').reverse()[0])) ? true : false;
            }                      

     },                        
 "alertText": "Wrong File Extension"
 },
```